# I can't figure out how to mount my drives properly

Tags: command-line, partitioning, mount, fstab, bind

I am trying to figure out a way to mount my two drives correctly.
I am running ubuntu (20.04.2) and I can't seem to find a solution.

I installed the boot partition  on my ssd and I also have a 4 TB hdd I want to use for data like music and movies.
Now my intention was to mount the hdd to the folder /home/hdd for easier access.
When copying files to that direction the files do not go onto the hdd, instead they get copied onto the ssd.
I guess I haven't quite figured out yet how the filesystem works.
I found out about the bind mount option, where I mount the drive for example to /media/data and then route it to /home/hdd?! Might that be the way to go for me?!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does [this reference](https://www.answertopia.com/ubuntu/adding-a-new-disk-drive-to-an-ubuntu-system/) help explain things?

Comment: What did you try to mount the drive?

Comment: I mounted the drive to /home/hdd and tried to copy files there. 
They ended up in that directory but they actually got copied onto the ssd and not the hdd. 
So the HDD has 0% usage. You know what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

Mount your drive

```
mkdir /home/hdd #create hdd in /home, maybe you need sudo 
mount /dev/xxx /home/hdd #replace xxx with sdb or how the name of this device is and mount it to /home/hdd
```

For persistance edit your /etc/fstab:
Syntax:

```
 <file system>                            <mount point>   <type>       <options>                           <dump>  <pass>
```

This you can copy, after replacing xxx:

```
UUID=xxx                                  /home/hdd        ntfs         defaults,nls=utf8,umask=007,gid=46  0       0
```

Comment: 1) You should nowadays mount by UUID instead of by device: device assignments may change during boots 2) The OP did not give an indication about the file format. Could indeed be `ntfs`, but you do not know for sure.

Comment: You're right, and UUID is safer

Comment: I already did that.

Comment: My problem is, that the files that I want to be on the HDD which is mounted at /home/hdd aren't saved on the hdd. 
They end up on the SSD instead?!

Comment: Then you don't mount the HDD correctly, please make a list which command do you run and post them, also run `lsblk` and show us the output @Mark